# The kotlin-android-extensions plug-in is invalid

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

The kotlin-android-extensions plug-in still reports an error when the app directory and project directory are added.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YQkB.png)

Comment: It’s called `kotlin-android-extensions` with an s.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to build.gradle in the project root directory:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```